# Set custom icon in the center of MaterialCardView

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, material-components, material-components-android

I am not able Set custom icon in the center of MaterialCardView. Here is my xml layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardPaymentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_margin"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBarContainer">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardPaymentCardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_cornder_radius"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

handle click in activity:

```
dataBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView<PaymentActivityBinding>(this, R.layout.payment_activity)
        dataBinding.setHandler(this)
        dataBinding.cardPaymentCardView.setOnClickListener({
            Debug.d(TAG, "cardPaymentCardView: onClick")
            dataBinding.cardPaymentCardView.isChecked = !dataBinding.cardPaymentCardView.isChecked
        })
```

Here result:

Not clicked:

[image]

And clicked:

[image]

But I need to put my custom icon to the center of CardView.
Smt like this:

[image]

I converted SVG to xml (by Android Studio)

I try this, but icon not show and not show in the CENTER of cardView:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPaymentCardView"
                style="@style/cardViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_cornder_radius"
                app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_credit_card_outline_select"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 6):

In short you can't achieve it with the standard `checkedIcon` provided by the component. You have to add a drawable/view inside the `Card`.

With the versions **`1.1.0`**, **`1.2.1`** **you can**:

- define a custom icon with the **`app:checkedIcon`** attribute
- define a color selector for the icon with the **`app:checkedIconTint`** attribute

Staring with the **`1.3.0-alpha03`** you can also define:

- **`app:checkedIconSize`**: the size of the icon (default `24dp`)
- **`app:checkedIconMargin`**: the margin of the icon (default `8dp`)

---

To achieve the same behavior with the 1.2.x and 1.1.0 releases you can do something like((but I suggest you avoiding this kind of workaround):

- override the margins used by the checked icon adding in the `dimens.xml`:

  ```
      <!-- Margin between the checked icon and the card -->
      <dimen name="mtrl_card_checked_icon_margin">xxdp</dimen>
  ```
- override the size used by the checked icon adding in the `dimens.xml`:

  ```
      <!-- Size of the icon to be placed when the card is checked -->
      <dimen name="mtrl_card_checked_icon_size">xxdp</dimen>
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Gabriele. I spend a few hours on this issue and your answer helped me. I even put a bug report on the Github, https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/795.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele. Custom size is what I was looking for. This should be on the public API of the button. Unfortunately this hack is the best we have atm.

Comment: Hi @Gabriele how to set different color checkedIcon Currently it's getting matched with the checked state color of the card.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<selector>` similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_gray_24dp" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_gray_24dp" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_gray_24dp" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_white_32dp"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Here my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640448/materialcardview-customize-materialcardview-custom-icon-svg-xml-when-cli   . Is this a correct approach to customize MaterialCardView ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `app:checkedIconMargin`

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardPaymentCardView"
    style="@style/cardViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_cornder_radius"
    app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_credit_card_outline_select"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    app:checkedIconMargin="10dp"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```